# Simulate TCP half open with golang

Tags: http, networking, go, tcp, http-proxy

I'm writing a golang app [test-proxy](https://github.com/GreyRockSoft/test-proxy) that works as an http proxy to simulate various network conditions so I can test the error handling paths in my other http applications.  Currently I'm simulating a request where partial data is returned, but I'm wanting to figure out how to add support for forcing a tcp half open condition.  What would be the best way to simulate this using golang?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "half open"? That's often used to refer to a _embryonic_ connection that's in the process of being established.

Comment: When I say half opened I mean half opened as defined in this post http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Comment: That requires working at a lower level than the application layer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314038/simulating-host-unreachable-how-to-achieve-implement-it. You could simply stop sending and receiving data in your app, but the behavior at network level won't be exactly the same.

Comment: If I close the read side of the tcp spcket on the server that will at least test if tcp keepalives are working correctly in the client application which may be enough...

Comment: If you shutdown reads I'm pretty sure the network stack is still going to replay to tcp keepalive packets (though it can't hurt to try).